# Adding new person and new deal at the same time

Tags: zapier, pipedrive-api

So I've got Zapier, pipedrive and Wordpress and what I'm doing is I've got zapier connected to wordpress through a webhook and I'm then creating a deal when a new entry is submitted through contact form 7.

The deal is automatically being created but the person associated with the deal is not being added. How can I create a deal, add the new person and link the person with the deal and make it all automatically happen? The goal is to send an email to the deal contact person email address once the new deal is created.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I can also report that adding a person via their ID rather than their name works. I was having the issue of the Contact Person failing to populate in the deal when trying to add them using their name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently working on this as well; What I had to do was create a new person first, and then create a new deal using the newly created person's ID to associate the deal with them.